# Changing the URL without Redirecting

Tags: url, browser, href

I've been seeing this on a few websites recently where a link has changed the href of the `window.location`, but the page does not reload when the link is clicked, and the page remains scrolled down by the amount it was before. Does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sites you're thinking about probably use the new HTML5 History API, which allows you to change the behaviour of the back buttons and the address bar. Here's a demo: http://html5demos.com/history

Note that most funny business with hyperlinks will confuse search engines. Make sure your site works acceptably in an ancient browser ([Lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) comes to mind) and/or read up on Google's [Ajax Crawling Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the URL in the browser address bar without reloading the page, do this

```
<a href = "#" onclick="var stateObj = { foo: window.location.href };history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "newpage.html");">Change URL</a>
```

**stateObj** = The stack in which the current state of the page will be pushed

**"page2"**: This parameter is currently being ignored by the FF.

**"newpage.html"** : New URL which will be displayed in the address bar

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

**Supported by**: FF 4.0+, Chrome 8.0+, Safari 5.0+, Opera 11.5+, IPhone 4.2.5+